# making a self looping method in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

i want to make a method that that will automatically update the value of a label by accessing the data from database after a fixed interval of time. 
Can such a method be made that automatically runs in the back end and  loops itself  after a fixed interval of time.

Comment: How about the page making a request periodically to sever? You may try ASP.Net AJAX Timer Control (http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX. Ingredients: 1 ScriptManager, 1 Timer, 1 UpdatePanel

Code :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Text = (new Random()).Next(1000).ToString() ;
}
```

This example fills the label with a random number every five seconds, now you can both change the interval of timer and C# code to what you like. For example you may set the label text to a value from database or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Threading and Timer control of AJAX may be useful in your case